# set state of Office UI fabric components

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using Office ui Fabric components.

I have a textfield and a choicefieldgroup . I would like to get the selected value of the choicefield and the textfield . I tried using refs but i get an error **`this.refs is undefined.`**

```
const Footer = (props) => {
    return (
        <div id="Footer">
             <div id="Para1" className={styles.row}  > {arrBottomPara[0]}</div>
            <TextField ref="textbox" className={styles.column} val></TextField></div>
           <Dropdown className={styles.column} options= {[
                { key: "1", text: "1" },
                { key: "2M", text:"2M" } ]}></Dropdown>
            <div id="CheckBox2" className={styles.row} ><Checkbox label={arrConfirmSignatures[1]}></Checkbox>  </div>
            <div id="Submit" className={styles.row} >
            <PrimaryButton text={ButtonText[0]} onClick={this._save }> </PrimaryButton>
            <DefaultButton  text={ButtonText[1]} onClick={this._cancel }></DefaultButton> </div>
        </div>
    )
}
 private _save() {
        console.log(this.refs.textbox);
        }
```

How do i get the value of the refs set for a dropdown field & textbox

Comment: Did you set `this.refs` somewhere?

Comment: I was checking this.refs in the console.log(this.refs.textbox)

Comment: Yeah I'm 99% sure you have to create the `ref` somewhere first: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html